# Get all parents from a subcategory

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table

```
id; name; parent_id
1   xxx   0

2   ccc   0

3   zzz   1

4   yyy   3
```

My goal is to get the category and get all the parents exemple:

Category with id 4

```
1.xxx

 3.zzz

   4.yyy
```

What i have done until now my model Categories

```
class Categories extends Model

{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function parent() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Categories','id');   
    }

    public function children(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Categories','parent_id');   
    }

}
```

My controler that gets the category i want:

```
   $data['cat']= Categories::with('parent')->get();
```

my blade

```
@foreach ($cat as $c)
   {{ $c->name }}
 @endforeach
```

I am a bit confused how to do this i have try for 2 days find tutorials and read other examples but i can't understand i am a bit noob i am sorry.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You will have to loop I think.

Comment: From your table it seems that your parent relation should be a belongs to, because you can only have one parent (because you have a single parent_id colum, thus a single parent_id value for each record)

Comment: Yes it is true but my ideia was in the controller put in on array for exemple if i have category with id number 4 the array will be $array = ['xxx','zzz','yyy'], if i chose the id 1 the array will just have $array = ['xxx'], but i don't no very well how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Relations:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

**Starting with parent categories:**

```
$parentCategories = Category::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->with('children')->get();
```

In view:

```
@if($parentCategories)
<div class="categories">
    @foreach($parentCategories as $parent)
        ...
        @if($parent->children())
            ...
            @foreach($parent->children as $child)
                ...
                @if($child->children())
                    ...
                        @foreach($child->children as $c)
                            ...
                        @endforeach
                    ...
                @endif
                ...
            @endforeach
            ...
        @endif
        ...
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

**Starting with child categories:**

```
$childCategories => Category::where('parent_id', '!=', 0)->with('parent')->get();
```

In view:

```
@if($childCategories)
<div class="categories">
    @foreach($childCategories as $child)
        <div>{{ $child->name }}</div>

        @if($child->parent)
            <div style="padding-left: 5px;">{{ $child->parent->name }}</div>

            @if($child->parent->parent)
                <div style="padding-left: 10px;">{{ $child->parent->parent->name }}</div>
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Dosen't work that give me all the categories and subcategories, but thanks

Comment: @FreeLancer I edited my answer with the reverse order.